# Dealing with a web api failure

Tags: web-services, api, http, httpwebrequest

If I have a web api service (Order Notification) that allows a third party client to call in (they must call in to us, not use pushing to them) periodically (every 10 minutes) and gets new orders it has not yet received, how do I deal with failures?

For example there are 10 new Orders the client has not received since they last called in. The client calls into our Order Notification service. We retrieve the orders we have not sent (10 in this case). We update these 10 Orders as sent and return the response to the client.

However the client did not receive the response (sometime happened after leaving us e.g. http time out or something else).

So now we have a problem where on our side we have marked the orders as sent but the client never received them.

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, can you assign the caller some sort of identifier and when the caller succeeds it replies back saying it has acknowledged the request? The server will never know if something failed on the client side unless the client reports it.

For example, when caller A calls in for the requests it may do something like this:

```
call -> http://server/requests
```

server replies back with some xml that contains the result set for this caller along with a unique identifier that it will track to know if that particular call had a response (you can time out this identifier after a reasonable period of time)

when the client gets the request it can call back again

```
call -> http://server/requestComplete?id=[generatedID]
```

and the server marks it successful.

Lots of API's require some sort of identification token so it would already lend itself well to this kind of send/ack messaging system.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to both sides of the system you could create a received request so once the client picking up the data has received it makes a request to the original host telling that it's received successfully.